# SQL Query to add row number that resets everytime the column value changes (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, gaps-and-islands

Was looking through `Row_number()` function in SQL Server to increment the counter every time the value changes. The issue is that I need it to reset on a change such that the same value can reappear at a later stage and the `row_number` still resets and starts from 1 back again when you order it by datetime instead of grouping all the same type together and assigning a rownumber.

For example:

[image: TableA]

when I do

```
select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by type order by datetime) Order 
from 
    TableA;
```

I get the below result (instead of the desired output shown above):

[image: Output]

Comment: Please provide intended output as well

Comment: Output added in TableA column Row number

Comment: @Sonu please don't provide input and output as images.

Comment: The dates in the final result set are obfuscated but this looks like a gaps and island problem.

Comment: The question is knocking me down, Whats that ?

Comment: Can you please share output as text so we can prepare easily demo.

Answer (score 2):

Such is a type of [Gaps-And-Islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem.

You can solve it by first calculating a rank for the groups where a column's value changes.

Then use that rank in the row_number.

```
WITH CTE_DATA AS
(
    SELECT *
    , (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [datetime]) 
     - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY [datetime])) AS Rnk
    FROM TableA
)
SELECT [type], [datetime]
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [type], Rnk ORDER BY [datetime]) AS [Order]
FROM CTE_DATA
ORDER BY [datetime]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [type],[datetime],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type],A - B ORDER BY A) AS 
RowNum FROM 
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [datetime] ASC) A 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TYPE] ORDER BY [datetime] ASC) B  
FROM #tble1
)A
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.